# Passing JSON to the server like GET/POST to get a file instead of ajax reply

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I've an object created in javacript with a lot of data and I serialize it to JSON to send it to the server. After this, the server must do somework and create a dynamic file, so it can be downloaded.
 For the last routine I created an ASHX but can be modified. Already I'm getting a "httpcontext" that I found in another question how to work with it to get the data from the JSON, so my question is not related about this.

The problem (more oriented to JS) is this one:

How can I sent the JSON to the ASHX as a URL/GET/POST to the generic handler to avoid the "ajax reply" and be the user open a new window with the link dinamically generated?

Thanks, sorry for my english (please edit) and kind regards!

Note 1: I can't use third-part code
Note 2: I can't use JSON.NET
Note 3: I can't save the report on the server so the response must be a generated file to download, even more, the download itself is the response of the server.

**---UPDATE----**

I've been read this question:
[Can I post JSON without using AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429744/can-i-post-json-without-using-ajax/4429951#4429951)

The only thing I don't understand from that question is how to make it work, thinking in that I've a "link" to download

Comment: because I'm generating the file dinamically, it's a huge report that I can't save in the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved the issue with this (in the right way).

I just take my json object and send it trough POST with a dynamic form generated with javfascript

```
var dataToPostInExport = JSON.stringify(queryToVerify);
//Convert To POST and send  
var VerifyForm = document.createElement("form");
VerifyForm.target = "_blank";
VerifyForm.method = "POST";
VerifyForm.action = "file.ashx";
var dataInput = document.createElement("input");
dataInput.type = "hidden";
dataInput.name = "mydata";
dataInput.value = dataToPostInExport;
VerifyForm.appendChild(dataInput);
document.body.appendChild(VerifyForm);
VerifyForm.submit();
```

Then in the ashx file:

```
            Dim DataToParse As String
            DataToParse = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("mydata")
            Dim JSSerializer As New JavaScriptSerializer
            Dim QueryToExport as my very own type!
            QueryToExport = JSSerializer.Deserialize(Of My Own Type)(dataToParse)
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you do not want to refresh the whole page so there is a workaround.

1) Ajax-load an iframe which is a separate aspx file for example.

2) In the codebehind of that separate aspx file, generate the file in memory and convert it to an array of bytes.

3) Then use Response to stream the bytes to the user.

Comment: Not bad.... I've to change some things, but it deserves a +1. I'll take it as last option, I think there must be a way to post a json to a ASHX :S